# searching a particular input against an arraylist of object type

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public void searchWatch(long srch){
    long s = srch;
    boolean found = false;

    for(int i = 0; i<watchStore.size();i++){
        Watch fd = watchStore.get(i);

        if(fd.equals(s)){
            System.out.print("item found");
            found = true;
        }

        if(!found){
            System.out.println("no such record");
        }
    } 
}
```

> this is a code fragment from one of my class. my question here is I want to test a particular input of type long against an arraylist of type Watch. whether the serial number exist in the arraylist.

but it fails due to an error " .equal() on incompatible types" whats the problem with the above code

the following is the revised code

```
public Watch findWatchBySerialNumber(long srch){
    long s = srch;
    Watch watch = null;
        for(int i = 0; i<watchStore.size();i++){
            watch = watchStore.get(i);
                if(watchStore.contains(s)){ // this pop an error called  suspicious call to java.utit.Collection.contains
                    System.out.print("item found");
                    return watch;
                }
        } 
    System.out.print("item not found");
    return null; // watch is not found.
}
```

> please how can I fix that.

Comment: fd is of type `Watch` while s is of type `String`.

Comment: You should post your Watch object detail and which field you want to search. i e: if you need to search "watch id" of your "watch", you should write "watch.getId.equals(srch);" I suppose that "id of watch" is also Long.

Comment: yh but I made correction to the code instead of searching by name I actually want to search by serial number... so I changed the code to accept parameter of type long.

Comment: @Nabstar, I edited my comment.

Comment: but I don't want to search what's in my field. what I want to do is to search my arraylist for that "serial number". because I already added some watches to the arraylist.

Comment: @Nabstar, see my answer. You can not compare a number with a watch, only serial number of watch(or sth is also number) can be compared with a number.

Answer (score 2):

When u do `if(fd.equals(s)){` you are trying to match A `String` with another object of type `Watch` and that is why you are getting the error.

You need to get the String representation of `fd` and then match it with `s`.

Comment: how would that be...?

Comment: can you post your `Watch` class. It depends upon your implementation as how how do you want to match. Right now to me it is same as saying that I want to match an array of integers with a single String. Only you would know the parameters on which you can match a String with a `Watch` object.

Comment: You should either implement the equals method for Watch class with string param or the toString().

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Watch fd = watchStore.get(i);
```

With:

```
Watch fd = watchStore.get(i);`
// use getter method
String fdString = fd.getSerial();
if(fdString.equals(s)){
        System.out.print("item found");
        found = true;
    }
```

See if that helps.

Comment: is there a way to search an arraylist for a particular serial say "watch serial". beacuse my arraylist contains watches and each watch has a serial number. so I want to search a particular watch by its serial number.that is already in my arraylist.

Comment: I updated the answer...I misunderstood what you were looking for. This solution should work provided you have a getter method for your serial numbers

Comment: I have everything in my watch class...the point is am using the watch class to add the whole object to an arraylist. after letting user of the class input all the information from the keyboard and then add that to arraylist. then how can I search for a watch using the "watch serial ".

Comment: The way to accomplish this is either use a getter for your serial number or override the toString() method to return serial number for each watch object. You then compare the value of that String to the parameter passed into your findWatchBySerialNumber() method.

Answer (score 0):

'fd' is an object of **Watch** and 's' is an object of **String**. Since these are two different classes, running a fd.equals(s) will throw the error.
To get it working, try overriding the toString() method in the Watch class and then do

```
fd.toString().equals(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to find by serial number then:

```
public void searchWatch (long srch){
    boolean isFound = false;
    Watch fd = null; // declaring variable out of the loop is better.
    for(int i = 0; i<watchStore.size();i++){
        fd = watchStore.get(i);

        if(fd.getSerialNumber.equals(srch)){
            System.out.print("item found");
            isFound = true;
        }

        if(!found){
            System.out.println("no such record");
        }
    } 
}
```

My suggestion: if you write your method name as search or find you should return an object. If you only need to know "is it exist", you can give a name to your method: `isWatchExist()` and add a boolean return type.

```
public boolean isWatchExist (long serialNumber) {
    Watch watch = null; // declaring variable out of the loop is better.
    for(int i = 0; i < watchStore.size(); i++){
        watch = watchStore.get(i);

        if(watch.getSerialNumber.equals(serialNumber)){
            System.out.print("item found");
            return true;
        }
    } 

    System.out.println("no such record");
    return false;
}
```

If you need to find object, you should add a return type of your object. Give a name that describes your method goal clearly.

```
public Watch findWatchBySerialNumber (long serialNumber){
    boolean isFound = false;
    Watch watch = null; // declaring variable out of the loop is better. and name of you variable should describe your object, same name is better.
    for(int i = 0; i < watchList.size(); i++){ // your list name should be "watchList".
        watch = watchList.get(i);

        if(fd.getSerialNumber.equals(serialNumber)){
            System.out.print("item found");
            return watch;
        }    
    } 

    System.out.print("item not found");
    return null; // watch is not found.
}
```